# Zabbix send email to only one user

Tags: email, notification

I configured trigger action to sending email to 3 users, but only one user recaives email notifications. I checked bellow:

1. All users set to enable email in media
2. All users set to availabity 24/7 and all severity alert
3. Email addresses are correct
4. Users are enabled

I found only one diffrence. User, who recaive emails have super admin role, others have admin role. Maybe someone has similar problem? What I have do to all users recaive email notification?

Screenshot from configuration:

### operation details

[image]

### Action

[image]

### Operation

[image]

I discovered one thing: change user role from User or Admin to Super Admin resolving my problem. But I don't want assign this role to notifications users

Comment: Check the log files of the Zabbix server and your MTA

Comment: Also make sure the users in question have email notifications enabled.

Comment: Users have email notifications enabled. Where I found log files?

Comment: The exact location depends on your distribution and your installation. Usually log files in Linux are located in /var/log/.

Comment: Thank You for tip. I see other behavior of system. When I changed user role from Admin to Super Admin. User recaived email notification. How I can edit Admin role or other role that to users assigned to it can recaive email notification? I don't see this option in Administration > User Roles

Comment: @GeraldSchneider according to our conversation in other question. I added more information to my original question. If You have free time, please help me :)

Comment: Hello, Is someone there, who can help me?